# How do I set up my _vimrc file on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim

I want to make some macros to customize some things on gVim, and apparently that's what _vimrc is for. However, I don't have a _vimrc file apparently, so I suppose I must set it up myself. How do I do this, and where exactly should I put it?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers It uh... takes me to _vimrc. That's weird though, when I searched for it I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You must create that file yourself in your `$HOME` directory. Don't touch anything that's located in `$VIM`.

Comment: I have a *global* _vimrc in my $VIM folder that's shared on several computers and on each computer I have a local _vimrc in the $HOME folder with computer specific settings *(mostly shortcuts to files I frequently open on those computers)*. What's wrong with that? What is the *right* way to do it?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, the "right" way is to never touch anything that's outside of your `$HOME` directory unless you really know what you are doing. Of course, you can do whatever you want there if `$VIM` is under `$HOME`. As long as you don't mess with runtime files. `$HOME/_vimrc` sourcing `$HOME/_localvimrc` sounds a lot better to me.